# Delete array elements in a embebbed document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

In a MongoDB I have a collection with documents with this structure:

```
{
        "_id" : 18,
        "name" : "Verdell Sowinski",
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : 62.12870233109035
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 84.74586220889356
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 81.58947824932574
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 69.09840625499065
                }
        ]
}
```

I am using **.NET**. I need to remove the scores array element with the lowest scores.score for all the documents with scores.type="homework".

In the example would be the 4th element of the scores array ("score" : 69.09840625499065).

I suposse I have to **group by Id**, **sort limiting to 1** and then use the method **DeleteMany** but I can´t get the code work

I can`t solve the problem. The code I´m trying and don't work is the next one:

```
var db = client.GetDatabase("school");
        var col = db.GetCollection<Student>("students");
        var filter = new BsonDocument("scores.type", "homework");
        var myresult = await col
                //.Find(filter)
                .Aggregate()
                .Unwind(x => x.Scores)
                .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$_id" }, 
                   { "minimo", new BsonDocument("$min", "$Scores.score") } })
                .Sort(new BsonDocument("minimo", -1))
                .Limit(1)
                .ToListAsync();
```

My classes:

```
 public class Student
    {
        public int _id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Score>  Scores { get; set; }
    }

    public class Score
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public double Mark { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: This is basically what you need: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#use-slice-with-other-push-modifiers

Comment: MongoDB University question?

Comment: Yes, it is a MongoDB University question MOngoDB & .NET. I´ll try the last suggestion.

Comment: I think to delete array elements is necessary use $pull instead $push. I´ve modified my answer adding a piece of code (wrong code, I can´t make it work). Any idea?